# gtk_widget_set_sensitive crashes program

Tags: c, user-interface, segmentation-fault, gtk3

I have a program written in C using the GTK library. In the GUI I have a set of radio buttons, and depending on what button is selected changes if an entry can be edited (or sensitive as gtk calls it).

I have made a struct with all the widgets that I need to pass to my signal handlers. It looks like this (with other widgets removed for simplicity).

```
typedef struct _gui_ctx {
    // more widgets in here
    GtkWidget *entry;
} gui_ctx;
```

And in `main` I define one like so

```
gui_ctx ctx;
```

My entry looks like

```
GtkWidget *entry = gtk_entry_new();
ctx.entry = entry; //add it to the ctx
```

My radio buttons look like

```
GtkWidget *radio_key = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label(NULL, "Key");
GtkWidget *radio_password = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label_from_widget(GTK_RADIO_BUTTON(radio_key), "Password");
GtkWidget *radio_random = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label_from_widget(GTK_RADIO_BUTTON(radio_key), "Random");
```

I attach the signal handlers as such

```
g_signal_connect(radio_key, "toggled", G_CALLBACK(use_key), &ctx);
g_signal_connect(radio_password, "toggled", G_CALLBACK(use_password), &ctx);
g_signal_connect(radio_random, "toggled", G_CALLBACK(use_random), &ctx);
```

The signal handlers are all basically the same. They are all the same type like so

```
void use_key(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data){
    gui_ctx *ctx = (gui_ctx *) data;
    GtkWidget *entry = ctx->entry;
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(entry, TRUE); // crashes here
}
```

The program crashes on the last line of the handler function. It says

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have tried to find why the issue is happening but it always crashes on that line. Both `data` and `entry` are not null so I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: Isn't *widget the object that was truly clicked by the user?

Comment: @prmottajr yeah widget is the radio button, and then im trying to set an entrys sensitivity based on that radio button changing

Comment: Maybe it is not null but in an invalid state, is it possible to print the current value of the entry for example before setting its sensitivity?

Comment: @prmottajr entry is 0x93a200 in main and 0xd8458b48d8558948 in use_key. now im even more confused

Comment: Just for investigation purposes, if you set gui_ctx ctx; to be static and global, and use it inside the use_key, does it work? (it should)

Comment: @prmottajr yeah that works

Comment: What is the value of the address of *event? The documentation that I found only had 2 parameters.

Comment: @prmottajr this actually fixed my error. The callback function was supposed to only have two params and i was trying to read a third, hence the random address. thanks